# SOAP WCF security issue

Tags: wcf, soap, soapui, wcf-security

Before migrating to WCF auth service called by SOPAUI with basic creds was ok. But when they added WCF i get the "Cannot verify security of the incomming message"

What to be able to call service?

thanks

Comment: Check the WCF binding that is now enforced by the server. Not everything is supported with SOAPUI.

Comment: how to check it?

Comment: You could refer to the link to learn how to configure ws-security in wcf [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/common-security-scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/common-security-scenarios)